# What is the ったい / -ttai suffix called?

Tags: grammar

In response to my [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/the-logic-behind-%E3%81%8F%E3%81%99%E3%81%90%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) about くすぐったい, I was told of the specific suffix in use, the "ったい."  What is this ったい / -ttai suffix called in English and in Japanese (or what would one call it if it does not have a specific name)? What exactly does it connote? Would someone be kind enough to provide me with a brief list of Japanese words using this suffix? (I found Dono's romanization hard to understand {sorry})

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LcTre93Ilyg&t=0m57s

Comment: Are you referring to http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/the-logic-behind-くすぐったい

Comment: @Andrew Grimm - yes.

Comment: Do you expect that each suffix in Japanese has a name (in English or Japanese) other than the suffix itself?

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito, yes I assumed as much. If it does not have a specific name, can you tell me how you would call it in Japanese?

Comment: I do not think that that is a reasonable expectation.  For example, what is the name of suffix “-ish” as in word “English” in English?  Linguists may have a technical term to refer to a particular suffix, but I do not know one.

Comment: The -ish in "childish" for example, is called a derivational suffix. I am not a linguist and have no idea what the name is, but as this site is frequented by linguists, I do not think that it is in any way an outlandish request.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the term “derivational suffix” usually means a suffix which changes parts-of-speech.  It just describes _one particular property_ of the suffix “-ish.”  If you want a term which describes a certain property of suffix -ったい, please specify which property you want to describe.  Otherwise, there is no way to answer that part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some from a standard dictionary (using ending-by search)
厚{あつ}ぼったい (thick), はれぼったい (puffy), 口{くち}幅{はば}ったい (bragging), じれったい (impatient), 平{ひら}べったい (flat), 野暮{やぼ}ったい (uncouth).

It's interesting to me how many of these have a ば row kana before the ったい, and ぼったい appears in the [dictionary](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%BC%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0), as being something that attaches to the stem of a i-adjective or verb (basically as a  strengthener).

This form seems common in 遠州弁{えんしゅうべん}, for example as in [this site](http://homepage3.nifty.com/hachimankotoh/koitai.html) which splits the words into plain ったい and ぼったい ending versions, and also in 静岡弁{しずおかべん}.

Answer (score 3):

Reading your conversation with Tsuyoshi ito in the comments, I guess you are asking whether -ttai is a derivational affix or an inflectional one. It is a derivational one.